# Transformar Collections em Stream

Tags: java, java-8

Haveria como transformar o seguinte código para java 8 Stream?

```
    setores = new SetorBusiness().buscarEtiquetaFuncionario(null, codDiretoriaSelecionada, codCoordSelecionada, uf, cidade, servidor, null, null, agencia);
    parametrosRelatorio = new ParametrosRelatorio("QtdUorgFunc", SaidaRelatorioEnum.buscaEnum(tipo));
    parametrosRelatorio.getParams().put("sub", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/relatorios/SubQtdUorgFunc"));
    if (!setores.isEmpty()) {
    List<Setor> listaSetores = new ArrayList<Setor>();
    Setor set;
    Map<String, List<Setor>> lista = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Setor>>();

    for (Setor s : setores) {
        if (lista.containsKey(s.getSiglaSetor())) {
            lista.get(s.getSiglaSetor()).add(s);

        } else {
            List<Setor> se = new ArrayList<Setor>();
            se.add(s);
            lista.put(s.getSiglaSetor(), se);

        }
    }

    for (List<Setor> l : lista.values()) {
        set = new Setor();
        set.setSiglaSetor(l.get(0).getSiglaSetor());
        set.setCodigo(l.get(0).getCodigo());

        set.getSetorImpressaoPDF().addAll(l);
        listaSetores.add(set);
    }

   Util.gerarRelatorio(listaSetores, parametrosRelatorio);
```

Comment: Um `Setor`pode ter vários outros setores dentro do `setorImpressaoPDF`? Isso é estranho. Se o setor pai e o setor filhos forem coisas dieferentes, a situação fica mais simples.

Comment: é isso mesmo victor  
Um Setor pode ter vários outros setores dentro do setorImpressaoPDF. ao final eu fico grupado com o código e siglasetor e uma lista . É justamente para relatório.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso daqui deve resolver:

```
Map<String, List<Setor>> map = setores
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Setor::getSiglaSetor));

List<Setor> listaSetores = map.values().stream().map(lista -> {
    Setor set = new Setor();
    set.setSiglaSetor(lista.get(0).getSiglaSetor());
    set.setCodigo(lista.get(0).getCodigo());
    set.getSetorImpressaoPDF().addAll(lista);
    return set;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ou então, pode usar esse equivalente, se você quiser ser um pouco mais breve:

```
List<Setor> listaSetores = setores
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Setor::getSiglaSetor))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(lista -> {
            Setor set = new Setor();
            set.setSiglaSetor(lista.get(0).getSiglaSetor());
            set.setCodigo(lista.get(0).getCodigo());
            set.getSetorImpressaoPDF().addAll(lista);
            return set;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Entretanto:

- O que você quer montar é uma lista de grupos de setores, e não uma lista de setores. A classe `Setor` deveria ter uma única responsabilidade, que é a de descrever o que é um setor no seu domínio da aplicação. Entretanto, a sua classe `Setor` está com uma segunda responsabilidade, que é a de agrupar setores de mesmo código para a impressão do PDF. Assim sendo, o melhor é ter uma classe `Grupo` para que cada classe tenha só uma responsabiliade.
- O nome do método `getSiglaSetor()` é redundante, pois uma vez que ele está na classe `Setor`, o sufixo `Setor` no nome é desnecessário e `getSigla()` já seria o suficiente.

Assim, com essa classe nova, acho que isso seria melhor:

```
public class Grupo {
    private final String sigla;
    private final String codigo;
    private final List<Setor> setores;

    public Grupo(List<Setor> setores) {
         this.sigla = setores.get(0).getSigla();
         this.codigo = setores.get(0).getCodigo();
         this.setores = setores;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public List<Setor> getSetorImpressaoPDF() {
        return setores;
    }
}
```

O código com o *stream* ficaria assim:

```
List<Grupo> listaGrupos = setores
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Setor::getSigla))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(Grupo::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Caso queira manter a ordem original, pode trocar isso:

```
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Setor::getSigla))
```

Por isso:

```
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Setor::getSigla,
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.toList()
        ))
```

Comment: Funcionou mas a ordenação não veio a mesma. Como posso fazer com LinkedHashMap no groupingBy?

Comment: Acho que com LinkedHashMap manterá a ordenação que veio da lista

Comment: @user2509556 Resposta editada.